# Usar string como variables - Python

Tags: python, string, variables

Es una duda que me hubiera gustado conocer hace tiempo,
¿Como declaro un string y lo guardo como variable?
¿Como opero con multiples variables que tienen como nombre "loquesea_n"? Por ejemplo, tengo miles de csv en una carpeta que se llaman: "csv_1" "csv_2" "csv_3" etc.

Comment: @CandidMoe Stack Exchange siempre ha alentado a los usuarios a responder sus propias preguntas. Siempre puede haber alguien con una mejor respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @ChemaCortes. Pregunta y respuesta fueron publicadas al mismo tiempo. No es como si primero hubiera preguntado y después encontrara la respuesta.

Comment: Está admitido hacerlo así. De hecho, cuando haces una pregunta tienes una casilla para añadir tu propia respuesta.

Comment: Recuerda realizar preguntas en el sitio en base a [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Aquí es importante conocer dos cosas:
La primera "f"
Por ejemplo:

```
b = 5
print(f"b es equivalente a {b}"
>>> b es equivalente a 5
```

y la segunda "eval"

```
a = "print("hello word")"
eval(a)
>>> "hello word"
```

Así por ejemplo se pueden hacer cosas como la siguiente:

```
dic = {}
for i in range(3):
    dic[f"variable_{i}"] = i 
dic
>>> {"variable_0":0,"variable_1":1,"variable_2":2}
```

O como suele ser común, operar con muchas variables/objetos que tienen nombre "loquesea_n":

```
l0 = [1,2,3]
l1 = [4,5,6]
l2 = ["a","b","c"]
ln = ["n1","n2","n3"]

listas = []
for i in range(4):     # Range n
    listas.append(f"l_{i}")
listas
>>> ["l0","l1","l2","ln"]

for i in range len(listas):
    lista_n = eval(i)
    print(lista_n)
    
>>> [1,2,3]
>>> [4,5,6]
>>> ["a","b","c"]
>>> ["n1","n2","n3"]
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva de ayuda, un saludo!